# How to get the id_token outside a controller in Asp.net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, openid-connect, httpcontext

How can I get the id_token returned by OpenIdConnect provider outside of a controller.

Inside the controller, this gives me the token:

```
string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

I need to get the token inside a service in a similar fashion. How can I do this?

P.S: I have already tried to use HttpContextAccessor but it does not return anything.

Comment: did you try using Sesssion?

Comment: Don't think I have. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean HttpContextAccessor does not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Using Session to store data/value, which can be used in different place within your project.

```
//store vaule
Session["idToken"] = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");

//Call session 
var x = Session["idToken"];

//empty or clean Session value
Session["idToken"] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `GetTokenAsync()` is an extension method to the httpContext. If this is true, then you could add the HttpContextAccessor in your startup / top level program.cs (depending if you are on .net 5 or 6)

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
//or
services.AddHttpContext();
```

Then in your class, you can go the well known DI route:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public async Task DoSomething() {
       var idtoken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi Marco, this exact implementation is not working for me. As soon as the execution reaches await httpContextAccessor..., the debug mode unexpectedly exits. The application keeps loading infinitely in non-debug mode.

Comment: Can you access any other object in the context like the current Request or User property or does this error occur to any property in the accessor. 
If this problem is not scoped OIDC, then you have to solve this first, before you can evalute the answers here

Comment: Yes, I am able to access all properties of HttpContext. GetTokenAsync() seems not to be working specifically

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on Marco's answer, you usually work with tokens in a filter / middleware, then inject claims into your service classes:

- A website would use the ID token claims as the Claims Principal
- A web API would use the access token claims as the Claims Principal

You can make the ClaimsPrincipal injectable at startup, and note that this is a per-request dependency:

```cs
this.services.AddScoped(ctx => ctx.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
```

This enables you to inject the ClaimsPrincipal class into a Service class as in [this API code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/logic/services/CompanyService.cs), so that it doesn't need to know about HTTP, just the claims. In my example the service class is also request scoped, and applies some claims based authorization rules.